# Unable to copy in bluestacks

Tags: windows-7, android, window, emulator, bluestacks

I am unable to copy more than 500mb files in bluestacks. I want to copy my obb folder to shared folder. But, I can not copy. I tried many file explorer but bluestacks stops working when copying progress reaches to 500mb.

Comment: By "stops working" do you mean it crashes?

Comment: means not responding

Answer (score 0):

How are you copying data into Blue stacks? Are you connected through LAN as you can also try to connect to your PC in bluestacks through searching for your PC under LAN (it searches for IP address of local system connected to bluestacks). Also you can [put your files inside a folder](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEsQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2F7labs.heypub.com%2Ftips-tricks%2Fhow-to-access-your-computers-files-in-bluestacks-on-windows.html&ei=2l_CUrHuAqLyiAfp7YDgDA&usg=AFQjCNHSccxJQ2O7ofKSazF0jPYPlLoyPg&sig2=JDFJNWKpBlBx0aeT2aFx8g&bvm=bv.58187178,d.dGI&cad=rja) and share it for all of the users. Bluestacks will detect it and you can copy files into Bluestacks.

Also you can try the method on [this](http://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/how-to-access-your-computers-files-in-bluestacks-on-windows.html) site.

Comment: I was doing same, but bluestaks hangs when it completes copying in between 400mb to 500mb.

Comment: I don't have bluestacks but have used it in the past. Is the obb folder you are trying to copy can be splitted into parts and then you can try to copy.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran into this problem when copying movies from Showbox and have not found a solution until now. I have tried increasing the RAM size with no luck. The only thing that did work was uploading to Dropbox.

But I recently tried trick which seems to work consistently:

- Open ES explorer (Install it if you don't have it) and click on the homepage within it.
- Then click `Clean Now` over on the right hand side - this brings up the ES cleaner.
- Clean all, then go back to the folder with your file and try copying.

This seems to work for me. I have increased my RAM size before this - although it did not work - but it could be the combination of both. I will try resetting my Bluestacks RAM back to stock and try it.

Comment: *Warning here:* ES Explorer is full of adware and junk nowadays. I would not recomment installing it anymore.